# How to sort a struct from binary file with sort c++

Tags: c++, file, struct

The compiler gives a mistake :Expression: invalid operator<. I think there should be a problem with the parameters, which receive the comparator, but I am not sure. Here is the code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm> 

using namespace std;

struct ticket{
    char destination[50];
    char  flightNumber[50];
    char Aircraft[50];
};

bool comparator(ticket a, ticket b)
{
    return a.destination < b.destination;
    
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 6;
    char mydestination[40]; 
    ticket newA[SIZE];
    fstream f;
    f.open("records.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    
    if (f.is_open())
    {
        
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(newA), SIZE *sizeof(ticket));
        f.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR\n";
    
    sort(newA, newA + SIZE, comparator);
    
    for (ticket& s : newA)
    {
        cout << s.destination;
        cout << s.Aircraft;
        cout << s.flightNumber << endl;     
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a.destination < b.destination` doesn't compare strings; it compares addresses (which exhibits undefined behaviors, since they are not pointers into the same array). To compare C-style strings, use `strcmp`

Comment: You should pass parameters of `comparator` as `const` reference, since you are not modifying them.  The reference prevents the compiler making copies of your variables (passing by value).

Comment: "Expression: invalid operator<" does not look like a message from any mainstream compiler. What is the actual error message?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text instead of character arrays.  You can compare `std::string` using `==`, but for character arrays, you'll need `strcmp`.

Comment: FYI, your program will still sort and print the tickets if the file was not opened.  Execution continues after the `else` clause.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `fstream f; f.open("records.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);` to `fstream f("records.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);`. Also, since `f` is used only for input, its type should be `ifstream` rather than `fstream`. That way you don't have to tell the constructor that it's an input stream: `ifstream f("records.dat", ios::binary);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, using `<` will just compare addresses.

To actually compare the strings you can use [std::lexicographical_compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare). Change your comparator to

```cpp
bool comparator(const ticket& a, const ticket& b) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a.destination), std::end(a.destination), std::begin(b.destination), std::end(b.destination));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "strings" are not c++, they are arrays of characters in c style. Therefore the best option for you is, as is suggested in the comments, to use:

```
int strcmp (const char* str1, const char* str2);

bool comparator(ticket a, ticket b)

{
return strcmp(&a.destination,&b.destination);
}
```

Or just delete comparator function and use:

```
    sort(newA, newA + SIZE, strcmp(&a.destination,&b.destination));
```

You may need

> #include <string.h>

But I would better rewrite my code in c++ style

Comment: It's not uncommon that data that is intended to be serialized is represented "in a lower level format", such as using `char` arrays instead of `std::string`. That does not means that we are restricted to use C functions, but your solution is indeed another good option. Also, if you need to include the header for "C string functions" in a C++ code, it's better to use `#include <cstring>` instead of `#include <string.h>`.